# ¿Cómo leer todas las lineas de un archivo de Texto en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, archivo, bucle-for

Estoy comenzando a hacer una función para analizar la sintaxis de un archivo. 
La función es la siguiente:

```
def sintaxAnalyzer(archivo):
    for linea in archivo:
        linea = archivo.readlines()
        print (linea)
```

El caso es que se me ocurrió correr el programa para ver si imprimia linea a linea y note que omite la primer linea del archivo, en cambio si dejo en blanco la primer linea y paso la primer linea del archivo a la segunda. Si lo imprime. Es decir, si tengo el siguiente texto en el archivo.txt:

1. Hola
2. Esto es una pregunta

En la función sólo imprimiría "Esto es una pregunta"
pero si lo modifico el archivo.txt de la siguiente manera:

1. .
2. Hola
3. Esto es una pregunta

Ya me imprimiría "Hola Esto es una pregunta"

Comment: Quita lo de `linea=archivo.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

#### ¿Cómo leer todas las lineas de un archivo de Texto en python?

Usando [readlines()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/readlines.html) puede ser suficiente:

```
with open('archivo.txt') as archivo:
    lineas = archivo.readlines()
    print(lineas)
```

para evitar los saltos de linea puedes realizarlo de esta forma, precisamente eliminando `\n`:

```
 lineas = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('archivo.txt')]
 print(lineas)
```

---

> **[readlines()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/readlines.html)** Devuelve una lista que contiene líneas del archivo.

---

en el caso del ejemplo de tu pregunta sería:

```
def sintaxAnalyzer(archivo):    
    lineas = archivo.readlines()
    print (lineas)
```

De esta forma imprimiría :  `"Hola Esto es una pregunta"`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario,  lineas = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('archivo.txt')]
Sin duda esa linea de código me hizo un gran favor